# How to make matplotlibs nbagg backend generate SVGs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Currently, I'm using the following at the start of my notebook to generate SVG plots:

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
```

When using the [`nbagg`](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html?highlight=nbagg#the-nbagg-backend) backend instead (like this: `%matplotlib nbagg`), plots are generated as PNGs. Is it possible to configure the `nbagg` backend to generate SVGs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Agg](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py) backend in matplotlib uses the [Anti-Grain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/) 2D graphics library to generate bitmap graphics. The documentation for the backend states:

> Output to RGBA and PNG, optionally JPEG and TIFF

The [NbAgg](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py) backend wraps the Agg backend (via [WebAgg core](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py)) and so is also limited to those output types.

Note that this simply defines the backend used to generate figures for *viewing*. Regardless of backend, you can still save figures to SVG format using `figure.savefig('<filename'> format='svg')` (or using a filename ending in `.svg`).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I'll have to try to tweak the dpi settings to get better quality. With default settings, svg looks much better than png.

Comment: @BjörnPollex you may be better keeping to screen resolution (~96dpi; default) and adjusting the figure size. Low quality of figures in the notebook is usually caused by browser scaling of the resulting image *after* it's been rendered. In Chrome (and probably others) if you right click and select "Open image in new tab" you can see the "real" image.